# Showing that the set $A = \{(x,y): y < 0\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that the set $A = \{(x,y): y < 0\}$ is open. I understand that to do this, i need to take an open ball centered at an arbitrary point in $A$ with a positive radius and show it is contained in the set. However, i'm not sure what my radius should be, or how to prove this formally.

Comment: Did you draw a picture?  What radius works for $(0,-3)$?  For $(4,-5)$?  For $(-10, -0.01)$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: If you've fixed a point $(x, y)$ with $y < 0$, consider the ball with radius $$r = \frac{|y|}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Choose $(x,y) \in A$, and let $U = B((x,y), |y|)$. $U$ is open, and if $(x',y') \in U$, then $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2 < y^2$. In particular, $|y-y'| < |y| = -y$, and so $y'-y < -y$, which gives $y' < 0$. Hence $(x',y') \in U$, and so $A$ is open.

Alternatively, notice that $f((x,y)) = y$ is continuous, and so $A = f^{-1} (-\infty,0)$ is open.