# Show that the set $\{(x,y): y > 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open - verification and criticism

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Show that the set $C = \{(x,y): y > 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open

I know a very similar question has [already been asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503162/showing-that-the-set-a-x-y-y-0-is-open), but I wanted criticism on what I did because I felt very frustrated in articulating my solution formally for an idea that I visually was able to put together quickly.

**Attempt**
In order to show that the set $C$ is open requires us to show that any neighbourhood of a point will be fully contained in the set. That is we must show that a ball, $B(\textbf{a}, \delta) \subset C$, where $\textbf{a} = (a_{1},a_{2})$.

My issue was in choosing a $\delta$ for this scenario and showing that it worked. I went off the tracks here thinking about open rectangles and balls inscribed in open rectangles with their radius being $\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{n}}$ and I frazzled myself in the process.

So using the "notion" of the open rectangle I settled on letting $\delta = \frac{|y|}{2}$, so in my particular case this would mean $\delta = \frac{|a_{2}|}{2}$.

With this as my $\delta$, let's take an arbitrary point $\textbf{x} = (x,y) \in B(\textbf{a},\delta)$. Now I have to show that $\textbf{x} \in C$.

I know that:

$$||\textbf{x} - \textbf{a}|| = ||(x-a_{1})^{2} + (y-a_{2})^{2}|| < \delta = \frac{|a_{2}|}{2}$$.

Now to simplify things we can assume that $x = a_{1}$, which then leaves me with

$$||(y-a_{2})^{2}|| < \delta = \frac{|a_{2}|}{2} \\
|(y-a_{2})| < \frac{|a_{2}|}{2}$$

which we can do by rewriting the form of the norm being used w.r.t absolute values.

This can then be rewritten as:

$$\frac{-a_{2}}{2} < y - a_{2} < \frac{a_{2}}{2} \\
 \frac{a_{2}}{2} < y < \frac{3a_{2}}{2}$$

Because we are only concerned in the positive value of $a_{2}$ we can remove the absolute value bars.

Since it was assumed $0 < a_{2}$, this shows that $\textbf{x} \in C$.

So my issues:

1. I feel my choice of $\delta$ is not right. At least it doesn't "feel" right in terms of how I ended up phrasing it. It took too much mental strain to articulate it properly, but when drawing the picture I could see the idea clearly
2. I think I missed a step because am I not supposed to also have shown that $\textbf{x} \in B(\textbf{a},\delta)$? I kind of just assumed it was there without establishing it.
3. My manipulation of the series of inequalities also feels off and not as fluid as I feel they should be.

Comments on my concerns would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: Suppose $(x,y)\in C.$ Then $y>0.$ Draw a picture! Doesn't it look like the entire $B((x,y),y)\subset C?$ (You chose the radius to be $y/2$ but it seemed like you were taking a stab in the dark.)

Let's verify. Let $(x',y')\in B((x,y),y).$ We want to show $(x',y')\in C.$ All we need to verify is that $y'>0.$ But we know $|x'-x|^2 + |y'-y|^2<y^2.$ This implies $|y'-y|<y$, which implies $-y < y'-y.$ Add $y$ to both sides to get $0<y'.$ We're done

Comment: In the implication that $|y'-y|<y$, did you just assume $x' = x$? and if not why were you able to just look at the one piece alone?...........I actually took  $y/2 $ because of the picture and how a distance of $y$ would be the distance from my point to the $x$-axis, so I took $y/2$ as "safety".....but it didn't work out I suppose.

Comment: actually I am a little thrown off....how do we know $|x' - x|^{2} + |y'-y|^{2} < y^{2}$ ?. By triangle inequality at most I could say is $|(x' - x)^{2} + (y'-y)^{2}| <|x' - x|^{2} + |y'-y|^{2} < ?$ (I'm actually not sure what each component would be less than...

Comment: There's an element of logic you're missing, We have $|x'-x|^2 + |y'-y|^2<y^2.$ Therefore $|y'-y|^2<y^2.$  As for $y/2$ I can now see you were thingking of a safety margin. There's no need for it, but it's fine.

Comment: Oh....I do see the element of logic you were talking about: $|y'-y|^2 < |x' - x| ^{2} +|y'-y|^2<y^2$. But my second comment still has me puzzled.

Comment: Is this how the reasoning should go:  So I know $||(x',y') - (x,y)||^{2} = (x'-x)^{2} + (y'-y)^{2} < y^{2}$. As a consequence: $y^{2} >  (x'-x)^{2} + (y'-y)^{2} > (y'-y)^{2}$. So I'm left with $(y'-y)^{2} < y^{2}$. Taking the square root of both sides I can write equivalently: $|y'-y| < y$ and from here I get your last line.

Comment: That's right, although the second $>$ should be $\ge.$

Comment: Thanks for the help.